# FCM + NodeJS BackGround Push Notifications

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently able to receive foreground push notifications and transfer them to a Snackbar in my web app. However, when I have the app in background, I check in my console that the message is received - but chrome pops no message about it. Is there something missing in this code? This is on my Sevice Worker file:

```
messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  console.log("event content ==>", payload)
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Background Push Received ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const { title, body, icon} = payload.data;
  //const {title, text} = event.data.json().notification;

  const options = {
  //  data: url,
    body: body,
    icon: '/gmp-icon.png'
    //vibrate: [200, 100, 200],
   // tag: tag,
   // image: image,
    // badge: "/favicon.ico",
    // actions: [{ action: "Detail", title: "View", icon: "https://via.placeholder.com/128/ff0000"}]
  };


  self.registration.showNotification(title, options);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need two files at the root of your `domain`.

1. **manifest.json**

```js
{
  "//_comment1": "Some browsers will use this to enable push notifications.",
  "//_comment2": "It is the same for all projects, this is not your project's sender ID",
  "gcm_sender_id": "103953800507"
}
```

2. **firebase-messaging-sw.js**

```
/**
 * Here is is the code snippet to initialize Firebase Messaging in the Service
 * Worker when your app is not hosted on Firebase Hosting.

 // Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
 // Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here. Other Firebase libraries
 // are not available in the service worker.*/
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-messaging.js");

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in
// your app's Firebase config object.
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-object
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "xxxxxxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

##### Procedure for testing:

1. Open your domain over `https://` protocol as the service worker is only enabled on `https` and not `http`
2. Allow notifications permissions to your domain in the browser when prompted
3. Open another tab so that your `domain` tab is put in the background and minimize the browser
4. Send a test notification to your registered `FCM token` via the firebase console. More instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message).

If all is good, your browser will automatically show you default system popup notification. There's no need of any extra code in the service worker apart from what is specified above.

**P.S**: I'm assuming you have already integrated the logic for acquiring the `FCM token` and sending it to your server for persistence. If not you can refer to the sample [index.html](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/messaging/index.html) file.

***Reference:***

1. [Detailed Explaination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client)
2. [Quickstart Sample on Github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging)

Comment: I have indeed integrated all of that already. When I receive a notification, I can see it on the console, but no background notification is shown yet...

Comment: Can you directly try the quick start sample? Just replace the credentials in index and service worker and see if that works in your chrome. I think there might be something wrong with your service worker. You can also try unregistering the service worker via the dev tools.